# Как правильно сделать таблицу vue cli

Tags: css, vue.js, vue-cli

Использую vue2 cli. Есть таблица. Начала делать ее на плагине vue-tables-2, но уже думаю что без плагина нужно крутится. Проблемы таблицы заключается в том, что tbody имеет кастомный скрол. Немного подумав сделала thead position stiky и через calc вычитала высоту и top что бы скрол не наползал на шапку. Но так же требуется, что бы шапка не обрезалась, а уходила в право, так что бы было видно что там что то есть, а вот боди должно быть обрезано. При чем при скроле все скролится вместе(по горизонтали имею в виду). Прошу подсказать, нужно делить теперче на две таблицы шапка и боди?, тк в таблицу невозможно впихнуть кастомный скролл. Или же есть плагин который позволяет вертеть tbody по вертикали, а по горизонтали tbody и thead не используя позиционирования. На просторах интернета искала, но не нахожу ничего подходящего. Может у кого был опыт в таких таблицах. То что имею сейчас - https://codepen.io/KatushaSan/pen/wvjzYae

```js
Vue.use(VueTables.ClientTable);
Vue.use(vuescroll);

function getData() {
    return [
        {
            modal: 'что то',
            checkedId: 'check1',
            date: '85.12.3021',
            fio: 'что то',
            floor: 'что то',
            dateBeathdey: 'что то',
            area: 'что то',
            research: 'что то',
            idPacient: 'что то',
            quality: 'что то',
            AETitle: 'что то',
            direction: 'что то',
            registrationNumber: 'что то',
            priority: 'что то',
            institution: 'что то',
            appointed: 'что то',
            nameProtokol: 'что то'
        },
      {
            modal: 'что то',
            checkedId: 'check1',
            date: '85.12.3021',
            fio: 'что то',
            floor: 'что то',
            dateBeathdey: 'что то',
            area: 'что то',
            research: 'что то',
            idPacient: 'что то',
            quality: 'что то',
            AETitle: 'что то',
            direction: 'что то',
            registrationNumber: 'что то',
            priority: 'что то',
            institution: 'что то',
            appointed: 'что то',
            nameProtokol: 'что то'
        },{
            modal: 'что то',
            checkedId: 'check1',
            date: '85.12.3021',
            fio: 'что то',
            floor: 'что то',
            dateBeathdey: 'что то',
            area: 'что то',
            research: 'что то',
            idPacient: 'что то',
            quality: 'что то',
            AETitle: 'что то',
            direction: 'что то',
            registrationNumber: 'что то',
            priority: 'что то',
            institution: 'что то',
            appointed: 'что то',
            nameProtokol: 'что то'
        },{
            modal: 'что то',
            checkedId: 'check1',
            date: '85.12.3021',
            fio: 'что то',
            floor: 'что то',
            dateBeathdey: 'что то',
            area: 'что то',
            research: 'что то',
            idPacient: 'что то',
            quality: 'что то',
            AETitle: 'что то',
            direction: 'что то',
            registrationNumber: 'что то',
            priority: 'что то',
            institution: 'что то',
            appointed: 'что то',
            nameProtokol: 'что то'
        },{
            modal: 'что то',
            checkedId: 'check1',
            date: '85.12.3021',
            fio: 'что то',
            floor: 'что то',
            dateBeathdey: 'что то',
            area: 'что то',
            research: 'что то',
            idPacient: 'что то',
            quality: 'что то',
            AETitle: 'что то',
            direction: 'что то',
            registrationNumber: 'что то',
            priority: 'что то',
            institution: 'что то',
            appointed: 'что то',
            nameProtokol: 'что то'
        },{
            modal: 'что то',
            checkedId: 'check1',
            date: '85.12.3021',
            fio: 'что то',
            floor: 'что то',
            dateBeathdey: 'что то',
            area: 'что то',
            research: 'что то',
            idPacient: 'что то',
            quality: 'что то',
            AETitle: 'что то',
            direction: 'что то',
            registrationNumber: 'что то',
            priority: 'что то',
            institution: 'что то',
            appointed: 'что то',
            nameProtokol: 'что то'
        },{
            modal: 'что то',
            checkedId: 'check1',
            date: '85.12.3021',
            fio: 'что то',
            floor: 'что то',
            dateBeathdey: 'что то',
            area: 'что то',
            research: 'что то',
            idPacient: 'что то',
            quality: 'что то',
            AETitle: 'что то',
            direction: 'что то',
            registrationNumber: 'что то',
            priority: 'что то',
            institution: 'что то',
            appointed: 'что то',
            nameProtokol: 'что то'
        }
    ]
}
const BaseTable = new Vue({
    el: "#baseTable",
    data() {
        return {
            dataEl: getData(),
            ops: {
                scrollPanel: {
                    initialScrollX: 1,
                    initialScrollY: 1,
                },
            },
            columns: [
                'choice',
                'status',
                'modal',
                'dateTime',
                'fio',
                'floor',
                'dateBeathdey',
                'area',
                'research',
                'idPacient',
                'quality',
                'AETitle',
                'direction',
                'registrationNumber',
                'priority',
                'institution',
                'appointed',
                'nameProtokol',
            ],
            filterable:  [
                'choice',
                'status',
                'modal',
                'dateTime',
                'fio',
                'floor',
                'dateBeathdey',
                'area',
                'research',
                'idPacient',
                'quality',
                'AETitle',
                'direction',
                'registrationNumber',
                'priority',
                'institution',
                'appointed',
                'nameProtokol',
            ],
            options: {
                headings: {
                    status: 'что то',
                    modal: 'что то',
                    dateTime: 'что то',
                    fio: 'что то',
                    floor: 'что то',
                    dateBeathdey: 'что то',
                    area: 'что то',
                    research: 'что то',
                    idPacient: 'что то',
                    quality: 'что то',
                    AETitle: 'что то',
                    direction: 'что то',
                    registrationNumber: 'что то',
                    priority: 'что то',
                    institution: 'что то',
                    appointed: 'что то',
                    nameProtokol: 'что то',
                },
                sortable: [
                    'status',
                    'modal',
                    'dateTime',
                    'fio',
                    'floor',
                    'dateBeathdey',
                    'area',
                    'research',
                    'idPacient',
                    'quality',
                    'AETitle',
                    'direction',
                    'registrationNumber',
                    'priority',
                    'institution',
                    'appointed',
                    'nameProtokol',
                ]
            },
        }
    }
});
```

```css
.table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
  background: black;
    font-size: calc(100vw * 19/834);
    line-height: calc(100vw * 31/834);
    letter-spacing: -0.015em;
    color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto!important;
}

.table thead th{
    border-right: 2px solid #3E5266;
}

.VueTables thead tr {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #3E5266;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    background: #597A95;
}

.VueTables thead th {
    font-family: 'Inter-SemiBold';
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, #3E523F 0%, rgba(67, 91, 114, 0.00520833) 260.84%, #234636 260.87%);
}

.table thead th:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}

.VueTables {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.VueTables th {
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.table__edit-img {
    padding: 0;
    width: calc(100vw * 30/834);
    height: calc(100vw * 30/834);
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.table__edit-img img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.VueTables thead {
    z-index: 1;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}

.VueTables thead th:first-child {
    padding-left: calc((100vw - 320px) / (1024 - 320) * (7 - 2) + 2px);
    padding-right: calc((100vw - 320px) / (1024 - 320) * (7 - 2) + 2px);
    line-height: 0;
}

.VueTables__sortable  {
    padding: calc(100vw * 5/834) calc(100vw * 6/834);
    cursor: pointer;
}

.VueTables__heading {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.VueTables__sortable::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 4px;
    left: 4px;
    background-image: url('../images/marker-sort.svg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    width: calc((100vw - 1024px) / (2560 - 1024) * (18 - 12) + 12px);
    height: calc((100vw - 1024px) / (2560 - 1024) * (10 - 8) + 8px);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.VueTables__sortable[class*="-sorted-asc"] .table__wrap-sort,
.VueTables__sortable[class*="-sorted-desc"] .table__wrap-sort,
.VueTables__sortable[class*="-sorted-asc"]::before,
.VueTables__sortable[class*="-sorted-desc"]::before {
    opacity: 1;
}

.VueTables__sortable[class*="-sorted-asc"] .table__wrap-sort .arrow-up {
    fill: #D9D9D9;
}

.VueTables__sortable[class*="-sorted-desc"] .table__wrap-sort .arrow-down {
    fill: #D9D9D9;
}

.VueTables td {
    padding-left: calc((100vw - 320px) / (1024 - 320) * (4 - 2) + 2px);
    padding-right: calc((100vw - 320px) / (1024 - 320) * (4 - 2) + 2px);
    text-align: center;
    border-right: 2px solid #3E5266;
    white-space: nowrap;
    height: calc((100vw - 1024px) / (1440 - 1024) * (28 - 24) + 24px);
    line-height: calc((100vw - 1024px) / (1440 - 1024) * (28 - 23) + 23px);
    padding: calc(100vw * 4/834) calc(100vw * 6/834);
}

.VueTables tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #6B6D8A;
}

.VueTables tbody tr.active {
    background: rgba(255, 147, 80, 0.45);
}

.VueTables--client>.row:first-of-type {
    display: none;
}

.VuePagination__pagination {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.VuePagination__pagination-item {
    list-style: none;
}

.VuePagination {
    display: none;
}

.bottom-table {
    width: calc((100vw - 1440px) / (2560 - 1440) * (383 - 340) + 340px);
}

.wrap-table {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px;
    border: 2px solid #3E5266;
    /* border-bottom: none; */
    height: 100%;
}

.table__wrap-sort {
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    width: calc((100vw - 320px) / (1024 - 320) * (19 - 13) + 13px);
    height: calc((100vw - 320px) / (1024 - 320) * (16 - 10) + 10px);
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    right: 2px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.table__wrap-sort svg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.table__wrap-sort .arrow-down,
.table__wrap-sort .arrow-up {
    transition: fill 0.3s;
}

.VueTables tr td:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}

.table-characteristics thead {
    display: none;
}

.table-characteristics.VueTables td {
    text-align: left;
}

.__vuescroll.hasHBar .VueTables {
    padding-bottom: calc(100vw * 22/834);
}

.table__wrap-sort {
    width: calc((100vw - 1024px) / (2560 - 1004) * (19 - 12) + 12px);
    height: calc((100vw - 1024px) / (2560 - 1004) * (19 - 12) + 12px);
}
.table__status-item {
    width: calc(100vw * 20/834);
    height: calc(100vw * 20/834);
    margin-right: calc(100vw * 5/834);
    padding: 0;
}

.table__status-item:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}

.table__status-item img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
}

.table__status {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.table__status-color {
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #D9D9D9;
    height: 100%;
}

.table__status-color[data-color="green"] {
    background: #54EE51;
}

.table__status-color[data-color="red"] {
    background: red;
}

.table__status-color[data-color="black"] {
    background: black;
}


@media (min-width: 1024px) {
    .table {
        font-size: calc((100vw - 1024px) / (1440 - 1024) * (20 - 16) + 16px);
        line-height: calc((100vw - 1024px) / (1440 - 1024) * (32 - 26) + 26px);
    }

    .VueTables td {
        padding-left: calc((100vw - 1024px) / (1024 - 320) * (6 - 4) + 4px);
        padding-right: calc((100vw - 1024px) / (1024 - 320) * (6 - 4) + 4px);
    }

    .VueTables thead th:first-child {
        padding-left: calc((100vw - 1024px) / (1440 - 1024) * (10 - 7) + 7px);
        padding-right: calc((100vw - 1024px) / (1440 - 1024) * (10 - 7) + 7px);
    }

    .table__status-item {
        width: calc((100vw - 1024px) / (1440 - 1024) * (20 - 16) + 16px);
        height: calc((100vw - 1024px) / (1440 - 1024) * (20 - 16) + 16px);
        margin-right: 5px;
    }

    .table__check label {
        width: calc((100vw - 1024px) / (1440 - 1024) * (20 - 16) + 16px);
        height: calc((100vw - 1024px) / (1440 - 1024) * (20 - 16) + 16px);
    }

    .table__check label::before {
        transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
        width: calc((100vw - 1024px) / (1440 - 1024) * (8 - 6) + 6px);
        height: calc((100vw - 1024px) / (1440 - 1024) * (8 - 6) + 6px);
    }

    .__vuescroll.hasHBar .VueTables {
        padding-bottom: calc((100vw - 1024px) / (1440 - 1024) * (24 - 20) + 20px);
    }

    .VueTables__sortable  {
        padding-left: calc((100vw - 1024px) / (1440 - 1024) * (28 - 17) + 24px);
        padding-right: calc((100vw - 1024px) / (1440 - 1024) * (28 - 17) + 24px);
        padding-top: calc((100vw - 1024px) / (1440 - 1024) * (7 - 4) + 4px);
        padding-bottom: calc((100vw - 1024px) / (1440 - 1024) * (7 - 4) + 4px);
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .table__edit-img {
        width: calc((100vw - 1024px) / (1440 - 1024) * (28 - 22) + 22px);
        height: calc((100vw - 1024px) / (1440 - 1024) * (28 - 22) + 22px);
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1440px) {
    .VueTables__sortable  {
        padding-left: 31px;
        padding-right: 31px;
        padding-top: 5px;
    }

    .VueTables thead th:first-child {
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right: 10px;
    }

    .VueTables td {
        padding-left: 6px;
        padding-right: 6px;
        height: 28px;
    }

    .table__edit-img {
        width: 28px;
        height: 28px;
    }

    .vuetable th,
    .vuetable td {
        padding-left: 6px;
        padding-right: 6px;
    }

    .table {
        font-size: 20px;
        line-height: 32px;
    }

    .__vuescroll.hasHBar .VueTables {
        padding-bottom: calc((100vw - 1440px) / (1920 - 1440) * (20 - 24) + 24px);
    }

    /* checkbox */
    .table__check label {
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
    }
    .table__check label::before {
        width: 8px;
        height: 8px;
    }
    /* end checkbox */

    /* status icon */
    .table__status-item {
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
    }
    /* end status icon */
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1920px) {

    .VueTables__sortable  {
        padding-top: calc((100vw - 1920px) / (2560 - 1920) * (6 - 5) + 5px);
        padding-bottom: calc((100vw - 1920px) / (2560 - 1920) * (6 - 5) + 5px);
    }

    .table__edit-img {
        width: calc((100vw - 1920px) / (3840 - 1920) * (36 - 28) + 28px);
        height: calc((100vw - 1920px) / (3840 - 1920) * (36 - 28) + 28px);
    }

    .vuetable th,
    .vuetable td {
        padding-left: calc((100vw - 1920px) / (3840 - 1920) * (10 - 6) + 6px);
        padding-right: calc((100vw - 1920px) / (3840 - 1920) * (10 - 6) + 6px);
    }

    .table {
        font-size: calc((100vw - 1920px) / (2560 - 1920) * (22 - 20) + 20px);
        line-height: calc((100vw - 1920px) / (2560 - 1920) * (36 - 32) + 32px);
    }

    .__vuescroll.hasHBar .VueTables {
        padding-bottom: calc((100vw - 1920px) / (2560 - 1920) * (27 - 20) + 20px);
    }

    .VueTables td {
        height: calc((100vw - 1920px) / (2560 - 1920) * (31 - 28) + 28px);
    }

    /* checkbox */
    .table__check label {
        width: calc((100vw - 1920px) / (3840 - 1920) * (26 - 20) + 20px);
        height: calc((100vw - 1920px) / (3840 - 1920) * (26 - 20) + 20px);
    }
    .table__check label::before {
        width: calc((100vw - 1920px) / (3840 - 1920) * (11 - 8) + 8px);
        height: calc((100vw - 1920px) / (3840 - 1920) * (11 - 8) + 8px);
    }
    /* end checkbox */

    /* status icon */
    .table__status-item {
        width: calc((100vw - 1920px) / (2560 - 1920) * (32 - 28) + 28px);
        height: calc((100vw - 1920px) / (2560 - 1920) * (32 - 28) + 28px);
    }
    /* end status icon */
}


@media (min-width: 2560px) {
    .table {
        font-size: calc((100vw - 2560px) / (3840 - 2560) * (24 - 22) + 22px);
        line-height: calc((100vw - 2560px) / (3840 - 2560) * (39 - 36) + 36px);
    }

    .VueTables td {
        padding-left: calc((100vw - 2560px) / (3840 - 2560) * (10 - 6) + 6px);
        padding-right: calc((100vw - 2560px) / (3840 - 2560) * (10 - 6) + 6px);
        padding-bottom: calc((100vw - 2560px) / (3840 - 2560) * (8 - 4) + 4px);
        padding-top: calc((100vw - 2560px) / (3840 - 2560) * (5 - 4) + 4px);
    }

    .VueTables__sortable  {
        padding-top: calc((100vw - 2560px) / (3840 - 2560) * (9 - 6) + 6px);
        padding-bottom: calc((100vw - 2560px) / (3840 - 2560) * (9 - 6) + 6px);
        padding-left: calc((100vw - 2560px) / (3840 - 2560) * (37 - 35) + 35px);
        padding-right: calc((100vw - 2560px) / (3840 - 2560) * (37 - 35) + 35px);
    }

    .VueTables thead th:first-child {
        padding-left: calc((100vw - 1024px) / (1440 - 1024) * (12 - 10) + 10px);
        padding-right: calc((100vw - 1024px) / (1440 - 1024) * (12 - 10) + 10px);
    }

    .table__wrap-sort {
        width: calc((100vw - 1920px) / (2560 - 1920) * (23 - 19) + 19px);
        height: calc((100vw - 1920px) / (2560 - 1920) * (20 - 16) + 16px);
    }

    .__vuescroll.hasHBar .VueTables {
        padding-bottom: calc((100vw - 2560px) / (3840 - 2560) * (32 - 27) + 27px);
    }

    .VueTables td {
        height: calc((100vw - 2560px) / (3840 - 2560) * (39 - 31) + 31px);
    }

    /* status icon */
    .table__status-item {
        width: calc((100vw - 2560px) / (3840 - 2560) * (37 - 32) + 32px);
        height: calc((100vw - 2560px) / (3840 - 2560) * (37 - 32) + 32px);
    }
    /* end status icon */
}

.__rail-is-horizontal {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    background: #3E5266!important;
    height: calc(100vw * 24/834)!important;
    border-radius: 0!important;
    bottom: -2px!important;
    width: 100%;
}

.__rail-is-vertical {
    height: 100%;
    background: #3E5266!important;
    border-radius: 0!important;
    width: calc(100vw * 24/834)!important;
    right: -2px!important;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100%;
}

/* .mouseEnter .__rail-is-vertical {
    opacity: 1;
} */

.__bar-wrap-is-horizontal {
    background: #3D607E;
    border-radius: 12px!important;
    height: calc(100vw * 20/834)!important;
}

.__bar-wrap-is-vertical {
    background: #3D607E;
    border-radius: 12px!important;
    width: calc(100vw * 20/834)!important;
}

.__bar-is-horizontal {
    opacity: 1!important;
    background: #8495A2!important;
    border-radius: 12px!important;
    height: 100%!important;
}

.__bar-is-vertical {
    opacity: 1!important;
    background: #8495A2!important;
    border-radius: 12px!important;
    width: 100%!important;
}

.scroll-tabs .__rail-is-horizontal {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0!important;
    bottom: -2px!important;
}

/* .__vuescroll.hasVBar.hasHBar .__rail-is-vertical {
    height: calc(100% - (100vw * 42/834));
    top: calc(100vw * 42/834)!important;
} */

.__vuescroll.hasVBar.hasHBar .__bar-wrap-is-vertical {
    height: calc(100% - calc((100vw - 1024px) / (1440 - 1024) * (27 - 22) + 22px));
}

.__vuescroll.hasVBar.hasHBar .__bar-wrap-is-horizontal {
    width: calc(100% - (100vw * 40/834));
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
    .__rail-is-horizontal {
        height: calc((100vw - 1024px) / (1440 - 1024) * (24 - 20) + 20px)!important;
    }

    .__rail-is-vertical {
        width: calc((100vw - 1024px) / (1440 - 1024) * (24 - 20) + 20px)!important;
    }

    .__bar-wrap-is-horizontal {
        height: calc((100vw - 1024px) / (1440 - 1024) * (20 - 16) + 16px)!important;
    }

    .__vuescroll.hasVBar.hasHBar .__bar-wrap-is-horizontal {
        width: calc(100% - calc((100vw - 1024px) / (1440 - 1024) * (27 - 20) + 20px));
    }

    .__bar-wrap-is-vertical {
        width: calc((100vw - 1024px) / (1440 - 1024) * (20 - 16) + 16px)!important;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1440px) {
    .__rail-is-horizontal {
        height: 24px!important;
    }

    .__rail-is-vertical {
        width: 24px!important;
    }

    .__bar-wrap-is-horizontal {
        height: 20px!important;
    }

    .__bar-wrap-is-vertical {
        width: 20px!important;
    }
}

.wrap-table {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" {IF CLASSES}class="classes"{/IF}>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrap-table wrap-table--main" id="baseTable">
                      <vue-scroll class="scroll-table" :initialScrollY="true" :ops="ops">
                          <v-client-table
                              :columns="columns"
                              :data="dataEl"
                              :options="options"
                              :show-sort-icons="true"
                              class="table-main"
                              :filter="false"
                          >
                              <div
                                  v-for="(column, index) in columns"
                                  :key="'column'+index"
                                  :slot="`h__${column}`"
                                  class="bin"
                              >
                                  <span v-if="index !== 0" v-html="options.headings[column]"></span>
                                  <span v-if="index !== 0" class="table__wrap-sort">
                                      <svg version="1.1" id="Слой_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 15.7 16" enable-background="new 0 0 15.7 16" xml:space="preserve">
                                          <path class="arrow-down" fill="#808e9b" d="M14.2,8.6H1.5c-0.7,0-1.2,0.4-1.4,1s0,1.3,0.6,1.7L7,15.7C7.2,15.9,7.5,16,7.8,16s0.6-0.1,0.9-0.3l6.3-4.5 c0.5-0.4,0.8-1,0.6-1.7C15.4,9,14.8,8.6,14.2,8.6z"/>
                                          <path class="arrow-up" fill="#808e9b" d="M1.5,7.4h12.7c0.7,0,1.2-0.4,1.4-1c0.2-0.6,0-1.3-0.6-1.7L8.7,0.3C8.2-0.1,7.5-0.1,7,0.3L0.6,4.8 c-0.5,0.4-0.8,1-0.6,1.7S0.8,7.4,1.5,7.4z"/>
                                      </svg>
                                  </span>
                              </div>
                              <template slot="h__choice">
                                  <button class="table__edit-img" @click="updateTable">
                                      <img :src="imgUpdate" alt="" width="22" height="22">
                                  </button>
                              </template>
                              <div class="table__status glyphicon glyphicon-star" slot="status" slot-scope="props">
                                  <button class="table__status-item" v-for="(item, index) in props.row.status.slice(0, 7)" :key="'status-table-'+index">
                                      <img v-if="item.statusImg" :src="item.statusImg" :alt="item.statusText" width="" height="" />
                                      <div v-if="item.color" class="table__status-color" :data-color="item.color">
                                          <!-- выпадающий список из цветов, наверное, пока застилить кружком -->
                                          <!-- <div>color</div> -->
                                      </div>
                                  </button>
                              </div>
                              <div slot="dateTime" slot-scope="props" v-html="props.row.date"></div>
                          </v-client-table>
                      </vue-scroll>
    
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.7.0/dist/vue.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-tables-2@2.3.5/dist/vue-tables-2.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuescroll@4.17.5/dist/vuescroll.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Буду благодарна за совет. Схематично накинула как это выглядеть должно [image: https://monosnap.com/file/R5MbVgF1zTjSVKM8DdV0OAjpCdgDUJ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Вариант 1**

1. При монтировании и загрузке данными таблицы делаем ширину колонок в `thaed` и `tbody` одинаковыми.
2. При клике на `table header` , делаем его активным и позволяем обрабатывать только его скрол, аналогично при клике на `table body`, для сенсорных нужно будет обрабатывать касания.
3. При скролировании делаем скрол другого элемента на ту же позицию
   В случае прокрутки колесиком `table body` запоминаем верткальную позицию прокрутки (как при скроле)

```js
function getData() {
    return Array.from(new Array(7)).fill(
        {
            modal: 'что то',
            checkedId: 'check1',
            date: '85.12.3021',
            fio: 'что то',
            floor: 'что то',
            dateBeathdey: 'что то',
            area: 'что то',
            research: 'что то',
            idPacient: 'что то',
            quality: 'что то',
            AETitle: 'что то',
            direction: 'что то',
            registrationNumber: 'что то',
            priority: 'что то',
            institution: 'что то',
            appointed: 'что то',
            nameProtokol: 'что то',
            //status: ['статус','статус','статус','статус','статус','статус','статус','статус','статус','статус','статус']
        })

}

new Vue({
    el: "#app",

    data() {
        return {
            count: 0,
            active: 'head or body', // костыльчик 1 (конфликт скроллинга)
            scrollXPos: 0,
            scrollYPos: 0, // костыльчик 3 (позиция скрола по высоте)
            dataEl: getData(),
            columns: [
                'choice',
                'status',
                'modal',
                'date', // <- было 'dateTime' (найти данные в объекте)
                'fio',
                'floor',
                'dateBeathdey',
                'area',
                'research',
                'idPacient',
                'quality',
                'AETitle',
                'direction',
                'registrationNumber',
                'priority',
                'institution',
                'appointed',
                'nameProtokol',
            ],
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        const th = this.$refs.thead.querySelector('table thead tr')
        const tr = this.$refs.tbody.querySelector('table tbody tr')
        const h = Array.from(th.querySelectorAll('th'))
        const r = Array.from(tr.querySelectorAll('td'))
        for (c in r){
            const minColumnWidth = 100
            w = Math.max(Math.min(h[c].clientWidth, r[c].clientWidth), minColumnWidth)
            h[c].style.maxWidth = `${w}px`
            h[c].style.width = `${w}px`
            r[c].style.maxWidth = `${w}px`
            r[c].style.width = `${w}px` 
        }
    },
    methods: {
        activate(e) { this.active = 'head' },
        scrollHanlder(e) {
            if (this.active === 'head'){
                this.$refs.tbody.scroll(e.target.scrollLeft, this.scrollYPos) 
            }
        },
        activate2(e) { this.active = 'body' },
        scrollHanlder2(e) {
            this.scrollYPos = e.target.scrollTop
            if (this.active === 'body'){
                this.$refs.thead.scroll(e.target.scrollLeft, 0)
            }
        }
    },
})
```

```css
.header-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 40px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
.fix-header { /* костыльчик 4 (дополнить скролл) */
    min-width: 25vw; /* = (100vw - .body-wrapper.width) */
}
.body-wrapper {
    width: 75vw;
    height: 120px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
.theader {
    width: 200%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.table thead th{
    border-right: 2px solid #3E5266;
    font-family: 'Inter-SemiBold';
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, #3E523F 0%, rgba(67, 91, 114, 0.00520833) 260.84%, #234636 260.87%);
}
tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #6B6D8A;
}
.table { /* костыльчик 2 (сделать таблицы одинаковой ширины) */
    min-width: 3000px;
    width: 3000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.7.0/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
    <div class="header-wrapper" ref="thead" @scroll="scrollHanlder" @mousedown="activate">
        <table border="1" class="theader table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th v-for="(item, index) in columns">{{item}}</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
        <div class="fix-header">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <div class="body-wrapper" ref="tbody" @scroll="scrollHanlder2" @mousedown="activate2" @wheel="scrollHanlder2">
        <table border="1" class="theader table">
            <tbody>
                <tr v-for="(row, index) in dataEl">
                    <td v-for="(item, index) in columns">{{row[item]}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

*Стили я прописал минимальные, просто чтобы можно было видеть основные моменты. На счет сортировки можно попробовать посмотреть например такой [пример](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sort_table.asp) и реализовать что-то похожее для этих данных. Заголовки колонок не подменял - для экономии места и наглядности.*

**Вариант 2**:

Этот вариант экзотический, и понятное дело тоже немного костыльный. По части горизонтального скрола я его не доделал нужен тот же фикс что был в пеовом варианте (JS:создать и внедрить элемент после таблицы) По поводу общего исполнения, в данном случае понадобилось только дописать `css`,  где clip-path задает Г-образную форму таблицы и скроллбары смещаются:

```
.scroll-table.__vuescroll.hasVBar.hasHBar {
   clip-path: polygon(100% 0%,100% 23%,95% 23%,95% 100%,0% 100%,0% 0%);
}
.__rail-is-vertical{
    top: 23% !important;
    right: 5% !important;
    z-index: 1;
    max-height: 77%; 
}
.__rail-is-horizontal{
    max-width: 95%;
}
```

Посмотреть результат можно тут

```css
 .table {border-collapse: collapse;background: black;font-size: calc(100vw * 19/834);line-height: calc(100vw * 31/834);letter-spacing: -0.015em;color: #fff;width: 100%;overflow: auto!important;}.table thead th{border-right: 2px solid #3E5266;}.VueTables thead tr {border-bottom: 2px solid #3E5266;position: relative;z-index: 1;background: #597A95;}.VueTables thead th {font-family: 'Inter-SemiBold';background: linear-gradient(180deg, #3E523F 0%, rgba(67, 91, 114, 0.00520833) 260.84%, #234636 260.87%);}.table thead th:last-child {border-right: none;}.VueTables {border-collapse: collapse;}.VueTables th {white-space: nowrap;font-weight: normal;}.table__edit-img {padding: 0;width: calc(100vw * 30/834);height: calc(100vw * 30/834);vertical-align: middle;}.table__edit-img img {width: 100%;height: 100%;object-fit: cover;}.VueTables thead {z-index: 1;position: sticky;top: 0;}.VueTables thead th:first-child {padding-left: calc((100vw - 320px) / (1024 - 320) * (7 - 2) + 2px);padding-right: calc((100vw - 320px) / (1024 - 320) * (7 - 2) + 2px);line-height: 0;}.VueTables__sortable {padding: calc(100vw * 5/834) calc(100vw * 6/834);cursor: pointer;}.VueTables__heading {display: inline-block;vertical-align: middle;}.VueTables__sortable::before {content: '';position: absolute;bottom: 4px;left: 4px;background-image: url('../images/marker-sort.svg');background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: contain;width: calc((100vw - 1024px) / (2560 - 1024) * (18 - 12) + 12px);height: calc((100vw - 1024px) / (2560 - 1024) * (10 - 8) + 8px);opacity: 0;transition: opacity 0.3s;}.VueTables__sortable[class*="-sorted-asc"] .table__wrap-sort, .VueTables__sortable[class*="-sorted-desc"] .table__wrap-sort, .VueTables__sortable[class*="-sorted-asc"]::before, .VueTables__sortable[class*="-sorted-desc"]::before {opacity: 1;}.VueTables__sortable[class*="-sorted-asc"] .table__wrap-sort .arrow-up {fill: #D9D9D9;}.VueTables__sortable[class*="-sorted-desc"] .table__wrap-sort .arrow-down {fill: #D9D9D9;}.VueTables td {padding-left: calc((100vw - 320px) / (1024 - 320) * (4 - 2) + 2px);padding-right: calc((100vw - 320px) / (1024 - 320) * (4 - 2) + 2px);text-align: center;border-right: 2px solid #3E5266;white-space: nowrap;height: calc((100vw - 1024px) / (1440 - 1024) * (28 - 24) + 24px);line-height: calc((100vw - 1024px) / (1440 - 1024) * (28 - 23) + 23px);padding: calc(100vw * 4/834) calc(100vw * 6/834);}.VueTables tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #6B6D8A;}.VueTables tbody tr.active {background: rgba(255, 147, 80, 0.45);}.VueTables--client>.row:first-of-type {display: none;}.VuePagination__pagination {display: flex;align-items: center;}.VuePagination__pagination-item {list-style: none;}.VuePagination {display: none;}.bottom-table {width: calc((100vw - 1440px) / (2560 - 1440) * (383 - 340) + 340px);}.wrap-table {position: relative;overflow: hidden;border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px;border: 2px solid #3E5266;height: 100%;}.table__wrap-sort {display: flex;position: absolute;width: calc((100vw - 320px) / (1024 - 320) * (19 - 13) + 13px);height: calc((100vw - 320px) / (1024 - 320) * (16 - 10) + 10px);top: 50%;transform: translateY(-50%);right: 2px;opacity: 0;transition: opacity 0.3s;}.table__wrap-sort svg {width: 100%;height: 100%;}.table__wrap-sort .arrow-down, .table__wrap-sort .arrow-up {transition: fill 0.3s;}.VueTables tr td:last-child {border-right: none;}.table-characteristics thead {display: none;}.table-characteristics.VueTables td {text-align: left;}.__vuescroll.hasHBar .VueTables {padding-bottom: calc(100vw * 22/834);}.table__wrap-sort {width: calc((100vw - 1024px) / (2560 - 1004) * (19 - 12) + 12px);height: calc((100vw - 1024px) / (2560 - 1004) * (19 - 12) + 12px);}.table__status-item {width: calc(100vw * 20/834);height: calc(100vw * 20/834);margin-right: calc(100vw * 5/834);padding: 0;}.table__status-item:last-child {margin-right: 0;}.table__status-item img {width: 100%;height: 100%;object-fit: contain;}.table__status {display: flex;align-items: center;}.table__status-color {border-radius: 50%;background: #fff;border: 2px solid #D9D9D9;height: 100%;}.table__status-color[data-color="green"] {background: #54EE51;}.table__status-color[data-color="red"] {background: red;}.table__status-color[data-color="black"] {background: black;}@media (min-width: 1024px) {.table {font-size: calc((100vw - 1024px) / (1440 - 1024) * (20 - 16) + 16px);line-height: calc((100vw - 1024px) / (1440 - 1024) * (32 - 26) + 26px);}.VueTables td {padding-left: calc((100vw - 1024px) / (1024 - 320) * (6 - 4) + 4px);padding-right: calc((100vw - 1024px) / (1024 - 320) * (6 - 4) + 4px);}.VueTables thead th:first-child {padding-left: calc((100vw - 1024px) / (1440 - 1024) * (10 - 7) + 7px);padding-right: calc((100vw - 1024px) / (1440 - 1024) * (10 - 7) + 7px);}.table__status-item {width: calc((100vw - 1024px) / (1440 - 1024) * (20 - 16) + 16px);height: calc((100vw - 1024px) / (1440 - 1024) * (20 - 16) + 16px);margin-right: 5px;}.table__check label {width: calc((100vw - 1024px) / (1440 - 1024) * (20 - 16) + 16px);height: calc((100vw - 1024px) / (1440 - 1024) * (20 - 16) + 16px);}.table__check label::before {transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);width: calc((100vw - 1024px) / (1440 - 1024) * (8 - 6) + 6px);height: calc((100vw - 1024px) / (1440 - 1024) * (8 - 6) + 6px);}.__vuescroll.hasHBar .VueTables {padding-bottom: calc((100vw - 1024px) / (1440 - 1024) * (24 - 20) + 20px);}.VueTables__sortable {padding-left: calc((100vw - 1024px) / (1440 - 1024) * (28 - 17) + 24px);padding-right: calc((100vw - 1024px) / (1440 - 1024) * (28 - 17) + 24px);padding-top: calc((100vw - 1024px) / (1440 - 1024) * (7 - 4) + 4px);padding-bottom: calc((100vw - 1024px) / (1440 - 1024) * (7 - 4) + 4px);cursor: pointer;}.table__edit-img {width: calc((100vw - 1024px) / (1440 - 1024) * (28 - 22) + 22px);height: calc((100vw - 1024px) / (1440 - 1024) * (28 - 22) + 22px);}}@media (min-width: 1440px) {.VueTables__sortable {padding-left: 31px;padding-right: 31px;padding-top: 5px;}.VueTables thead th:first-child {padding-left: 10px;padding-right: 10px;}.VueTables td {padding-left: 6px;padding-right: 6px;height: 28px;}.table__edit-img {width: 28px;height: 28px;}.vuetable th, .vuetable td {padding-left: 6px;padding-right: 6px;}.table {font-size: 20px;line-height: 32px;}.__vuescroll.hasHBar .VueTables {padding-bottom: calc((100vw - 1440px) / (1920 - 1440) * (20 - 24) + 24px);}.table__check label {width: 20px;height: 20px;}.table__check label::before {width: 8px;height: 8px;}.table__status-item {width: 20px;height: 20px;}}@media screen and (min-width: 1920px) {.VueTables__sortable {padding-top: calc((100vw - 1920px) / (2560 - 1920) * (6 - 5) + 5px);padding-bottom: calc((100vw - 1920px) / (2560 - 1920) * (6 - 5) + 5px);}.table__edit-img {width: calc((100vw - 1920px) / (3840 - 1920) * (36 - 28) + 28px);height: calc((100vw - 1920px) / (3840 - 1920) * (36 - 28) + 28px);}.vuetable th, .vuetable td {padding-left: calc((100vw - 1920px) / (3840 - 1920) * (10 - 6) + 6px);padding-right: calc((100vw - 1920px) / (3840 - 1920) * (10 - 6) + 6px);}.table {font-size: calc((100vw - 1920px) / (2560 - 1920) * (22 - 20) + 20px);line-height: calc((100vw - 1920px) / (2560 - 1920) * (36 - 32) + 32px);}.__vuescroll.hasHBar .VueTables {padding-bottom: calc((100vw - 1920px) / (2560 - 1920) * (27 - 20) + 20px);}.VueTables td {height: calc((100vw - 1920px) / (2560 - 1920) * (31 - 28) + 28px);}.table__check label {width: calc((100vw - 1920px) / (3840 - 1920) * (26 - 20) + 20px);height: calc((100vw - 1920px) / (3840 - 1920) * (26 - 20) + 20px);}.table__check label::before {width: calc((100vw - 1920px) / (3840 - 1920) * (11 - 8) + 8px);height: calc((100vw - 1920px) / (3840 - 1920) * (11 - 8) + 8px);}.table__status-item {width: calc((100vw - 1920px) / (2560 - 1920) * (32 - 28) + 28px);height: calc((100vw - 1920px) / (2560 - 1920) * (32 - 28) + 28px);}}@media (min-width: 2560px) {.table {font-size: calc((100vw - 2560px) / (3840 - 2560) * (24 - 22) + 22px);line-height: calc((100vw - 2560px) / (3840 - 2560) * (39 - 36) + 36px);}.VueTables td {padding-left: calc((100vw - 2560px) / (3840 - 2560) * (10 - 6) + 6px);padding-right: calc((100vw - 2560px) / (3840 - 2560) * (10 - 6) + 6px);padding-bottom: calc((100vw - 2560px) / (3840 - 2560) * (8 - 4) + 4px);padding-top: calc((100vw - 2560px) / (3840 - 2560) * (5 - 4) + 4px);}.VueTables__sortable {padding-top: calc((100vw - 2560px) / (3840 - 2560) * (9 - 6) + 6px);padding-bottom: calc((100vw - 2560px) / (3840 - 2560) * (9 - 6) + 6px);padding-left: calc((100vw - 2560px) / (3840 - 2560) * (37 - 35) + 35px);padding-right: calc((100vw - 2560px) / (3840 - 2560) * (37 - 35) + 35px);}.VueTables thead th:first-child {padding-left: calc((100vw - 1024px) / (1440 - 1024) * (12 - 10) + 10px);padding-right: calc((100vw - 1024px) / (1440 - 1024) * (12 - 10) + 10px);}.table__wrap-sort {width: calc((100vw - 1920px) / (2560 - 1920) * (23 - 19) + 19px);height: calc((100vw - 1920px) / (2560 - 1920) * (20 - 16) + 16px);}.__vuescroll.hasHBar .VueTables {padding-bottom: calc((100vw - 2560px) / (3840 - 2560) * (32 - 27) + 27px);}.VueTables td {height: calc((100vw - 2560px) / (3840 - 2560) * (39 - 31) + 31px);}.table__status-item {width: calc((100vw - 2560px) / (3840 - 2560) * (37 - 32) + 32px);height: calc((100vw - 2560px) / (3840 - 2560) * (37 - 32) + 32px);}}.__rail-is-horizontal {display: flex;align-items: center;background: #3E5266!important;height: calc(100vw * 24/834)!important;border-radius: 0!important;bottom: -2px!important;width: 100%;}.__rail-is-vertical {height: 100%;background: #3E5266!important;border-radius: 0!important;width: calc(100vw * 24/834)!important;right: -2px!important;display: flex;justify-content: center;height: 100%;}.__bar-wrap-is-horizontal {background: #3D607E;border-radius: 12px!important;height: calc(100vw * 20/834)!important;}.__bar-wrap-is-vertical {background: #3D607E;border-radius: 12px!important;width: calc(100vw * 20/834)!important;}.__bar-is-horizontal {opacity: 1!important;background: #8495A2!important;border-radius: 12px!important;height: 100%!important;}.__bar-is-vertical {opacity: 1!important;background: #8495A2!important;border-radius: 12px!important;width: 100%!important;}.scroll-tabs .__rail-is-horizontal {width: 100%;margin: 0!important;bottom: -2px!important;}.__vuescroll.hasVBar.hasHBar .__bar-wrap-is-vertical {height: calc(100% - calc((100vw - 1024px) / (1440 - 1024) * (27 - 22) + 22px));}.__vuescroll.hasVBar.hasHBar .__bar-wrap-is-horizontal {width: calc(100% - (100vw * 40/834));}.wrap-table {height: 200px;}
/******************************/
    * {
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    .scroll-table.__vuescroll.hasVBar.hasHBar {
       clip-path: polygon(100% 0%,100% 23%,95% 23%,95% 100%,0% 100%,0% 0%);
    }
    .__rail-is-vertical{
        top: 23% !important;
        right: 5% !important;
        z-index: 1;
        max-height: 77%; 
    }
    .__rail-is-horizontal{
        max-width: 95%;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.7.0/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-tables-2@2.3.5/dist/vue-tables-2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuescroll@4.17.5/dist/vuescroll.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrap-table wrap-table--main" id="baseTable">
        <vue-scroll class="scroll-table" :initialScrollY="true" :ops="ops">
            <v-client-table
                :columns="columns"
                :data="dataEl"
                :options="options"
                :show-sort-icons="true"
                class="table-main"
                :filter="false"
            >
                <div
                    v-for="(column, index) in columns"
                    :key="'column'+index"
                    :slot="`h__${column}`"
                    class="bin"
                >
                    <span v-if="index !== 0" v-html="options.headings[column]"></span>
                    <span v-if="index !== 0" class="table__wrap-sort">
                        <svg version="1.1" id="Слой_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 15.7 16" enable-background="new 0 0 15.7 16" xml:space="preserve">
                            <path class="arrow-down" fill="#808e9b" d="M14.2,8.6H1.5c-0.7,0-1.2,0.4-1.4,1s0,1.3,0.6,1.7L7,15.7C7.2,15.9,7.5,16,7.8,16s0.6-0.1,0.9-0.3l6.3-4.5 c0.5-0.4,0.8-1,0.6-1.7C15.4,9,14.8,8.6,14.2,8.6z"/>
                            <path class="arrow-up" fill="#808e9b" d="M1.5,7.4h12.7c0.7,0,1.2-0.4,1.4-1c0.2-0.6,0-1.3-0.6-1.7L8.7,0.3C8.2-0.1,7.5-0.1,7,0.3L0.6,4.8 c-0.5,0.4-0.8,1-0.6,1.7S0.8,7.4,1.5,7.4z"/>
                        </svg>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <template slot="h__choice">
                <!--
                    <button class="table__edit-img" @click="updateTable">
                        <img :src="imgUpdate" alt="" width="22" height="22">
                    </button>
                -->
                </template>
                <div class="table__status glyphicon glyphicon-star" slot="status" slot-scope="props">
                    <button class="table__status-item" v-for="(item, index) in props.row.status.slice(0, 7)" :key="'status-table-'+index">
                        <img v-if="item.statusImg" :src="item.statusImg" :alt="item.statusText" width="" height="" />
                        <div v-if="item.color" class="table__status-color" :data-color="item.color">
                            <!-- выпадающий список из цветов, наверное, пока застилить кружком -->
                            <!-- <div>color</div> -->
                        </div>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div slot="dateTime" slot-scope="props" v-html="props.row.date"></div>
            </v-client-table>
        </vue-scroll>
        
    </div>


<script>
Vue.use(VueTables.ClientTable);
Vue.use(vuescroll);

function getData() {
    return Array.from(new Array(7)).fill(
        {
            modal: 'что то',
            checkedId: 'check1',
            date: '85.12.3021',
            fio: 'что то',
            floor: 'что то',
            dateBeathdey: 'что то',
            area: 'что то',
            research: 'что то',
            idPacient: 'что то',
            quality: 'что то',
            AETitle: 'что то',
            direction: 'что то',
            registrationNumber: 'что то',
            priority: 'что то',
            institution: 'что то',
            appointed: 'что то',
            nameProtokol: 'что то',
            status: ['статус','статус','статус','статус','статус','статус','статус','статус','статус','статус','статус']
        })
    
}
const BaseTable = new Vue({
    el: "#baseTable",
    data() {
        return {
            dataEl: getData(),
            ops: {
                scrollPanel: {
                    initialScrollX: 1,
                    initialScrollY: 1,
                },
            },
            columns: [
                'choice',
                'status',
                'modal',
                'dateTime',
                'fio',
                'floor',
                'dateBeathdey',
                'area',
                'research',
                'idPacient',
                'quality',
                'AETitle',
                'direction',
                'registrationNumber',
                'priority',
                'institution',
                'appointed',
                'nameProtokol',
            ],
            filterable:  [
                'choice',
                'status',
                'modal',
                'dateTime',
                'fio',
                'floor',
                'dateBeathdey',
                'area',
                'research',
                'idPacient',
                'quality',
                'AETitle',
                'direction',
                'registrationNumber',
                'priority',
                'institution',
                'appointed',
                'nameProtokol',
            ],
            options: {
                headings: {
                    status: 'что то',
                    modal: 'что то',
                    dateTime: 'что то',
                    fio: 'что то',
                    floor: 'что то',
                    dateBeathdey: 'что то',
                    area: 'что то',
                    research: 'что то',
                    idPacient: 'что то',
                    quality: 'что то',
                    AETitle: 'что то',
                    direction: 'что то',
                    registrationNumber: 'что то',
                    priority: 'что то',
                    institution: 'что то',
                    appointed: 'что то',
                    nameProtokol: 'что то',
                },
                sortable: [
                    'status',
                    'modal',
                    'dateTime',
                    'fio',
                    'floor',
                    'dateBeathdey',
                    'area',
                    'research',
                    'idPacient',
                    'quality',
                    'AETitle',
                    'direction',
                    'registrationNumber',
                    'priority',
                    'institution',
                    'appointed',
                    'nameProtokol',
                ]
            },
        }
    }
});
</script>


 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Спасибо что дали ответ, но не соглашусь, что тут не про vue, тк использую эту библиотеку и плагин скролла, который нужно синхронизировать и учитывать синтаксис vue

Comment: Я лишь имел в виду что вопрос этот не зависит от Vue, можно выбрать все что угодно)

Comment: еще раз поблагодарю за ответ. Хоть он и не решил мой вопрос)) Я решила делать по другому и попытаться вразумить дизайнера. А связывание несколько скролл баров возьму на заметку для будущих проектов)

Comment: Вы кстати могли скрыть верхний скрол, но разумеется вразумить дизайнера лучше, а все же почему не подошел этот вариант? Еще у меня была идея воспользоваться clip-path но там нужно прикручивать отдельный скрол и немного заморочек с высчитыванием самого пути

Comment: Не подошел, тк синхронизирую плагин скролла. Но тут уже мой косяк, я даже не написала какой плагин) А про clip-path интересно, что там можно с помощью него сделать, у меня даже предположений нет)

Comment: @EkaterinaRatatui я добавил вариант с `clip-path` он правда немного поехал по причине того что я вырезал media-query  из css (слишком большой ответ не принимало) но для демонстации думаю сгодится. Просто добавьте указанные правила к варианту который в вопросе локально и тогда увидите лучше.

Comment: ужал старые стили - так работает, но нужно подгонять все равно

Comment: спасибо за потраченное время на доп работу)